# HTML : How to make a curve like this using HTML & CSS using border or box

Tags: html, css, border

```html
<div style="position:absolute; color:#E0922F; border-style:solid; height:140px; width:360px; "></div>
```

[image: Here the example of the curve picture]

[image: This is only i can make. This using border radius]

Please teach me how to make a curve middle of straight like using css

Comment: I only can make a straight line . I have tried using border radius but did not make a shape like in the picture. I have walk-through the internet to see example . But did not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this

```css
.red-box{
  border:3px solid #E0922F;
  display:block;
  width:360px;
  height:140px;
  position:relative;
}
div.left {
  border: 3px solid #E0922F;
  display: inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  right:-3px;
  top:50px;
  border-right:3px solid #fff;
  background:#fff;
}
.left {
  height: 40px;
  width: 20px;
}


.left {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 90px;
  border-top-left-radius: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red-box">
  <div class="left"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolutely positioned [CSS Pseudo Elements like `:after`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/) with `border-radius` and [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) to generally create this effect.

For an html element with a class of "container":

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
  width:360px;
  height:140px;
  border:solid 4px #E0922F;
  background:#fff;
}
.container:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  right:0;
  width:42px;
  height:42px;
  border:solid 4px;
  border-color:transparent transparent #E0922F #E0922F;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:#fff;
  transform:translateX(calc(50% + 4px)) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Create an `:after` pseudo element which has a width and height and is absolutely positioned relative to `.container`.

Give it a border  thickness and offset your `x` value by the same amount with `translateX(calc(50% + 4px))`. This says, move the element a distance of 50% of its width along the X-axis and add the border thickness to this calculated position.

Move it down to the middle of the container element with `top:50%` and center it with `translateY(-50%)`.

Give it a `border-radius` of 50% to curve the corners and set each quadrant's individual colour with `border-color:transparent transparent #fc0 #fc0`.

Rotate the element by 45 degrees to position the visible border quadrants' corners relative to the right edge of the container element with `rotate(45deg)`.

The main drawback to this approach is the pseudo element has to have a background colour to hide the container below it. [This CodePen](https://codepen.io/donmckenna/pen/ZjqjMz) shows a working example. If you uncomment the `body` background colour you can see this drawback.

But if you don't try to be too fancy and keep the background colours consistent, this looks to emulate the effect you are looking for.

Note: you can also offset the border thickness by using `right:-4px;` and `translateX(50%)` if you don't want to muddy up your `transform` with `calc()`. Either approach achieves the same positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way with only one element and less of code:

```css
.box{
  border:3px solid #E0922F;
  border-right:none;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#E0922F,#E0922F) right bottom/3px calc(50% - 24px) no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(#E0922F,#E0922F) right top/3px calc(50% - 24px) no-repeat,
    radial-gradient(circle at right,transparent 50%,#E0922F 50%,#E0922F calc(50% + 3px), transparent calc(50% + 4px)) right center/40px 55px no-repeat;

  width:360px;
  height:140px;

}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  
</div>
```